# Getting glyph names

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I can't get the XeTeXglyphname command to produce any output. My code is shown below. I suppose that this command produces a string as output; do I need to do something special to make this string part of my document??

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\font\latin="Latin Modern Math"\latin

\XeTeXglyph 34  hello \XeTeXglyphname\latin 34 goodbye

\XeTeXglyph 519 hello \XeTeXglyphname\latin 519 goodbye

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With up-to-date TeXLive 2014

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\font\latin="Latin Modern Math"\latin
\XeTeXglyph34:  \XeTeXglyphname\font34

\XeTeXglyph519: \XeTeXglyphname\font519

\XeTeXglyph999: \XeTeXglyphname\font999
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Has the command changed? From reading the XeTeX reference manual, I was expecting that I'd need \XeTeXglyphname\latin34, not \XeTeXglyphname\font34.

Comment: That makes no difference `\font` uses the current font

Comment: I see. I updated my MikTeX installation and it works, now. Thanks again.